# Is there something similar to __END__ of perl in python?

Tags: python, perl, comments

Perl has `__END__` which treats everything below it as comments (even there are syntax error). Is there something similar to it in python?

```
$ cat ./main.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Hello World!\n";

__END__

xyz
```

Comment: You could place everything into a `"""...triple-double-quoted multiline string ..."""`, and then don't use the string.  If you are using triple-double-quoted strings already, then use a `'''...triple-single-quoted multiline string...'''`

Comment: So there is no equivalent of `__END__` in python?